# react native ui kitten button icon

Tags: react-native, button, icons, react-native-ui-kitten

in react-native ui kitten Button when i want to make a condition about loading to show the Spinner icon it not work when the icon props return null or false

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7mi5.png)

when the icon exist it shows like this so its good for me
[image of app response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIpMB.png)

but when the response is false i gives a error i hope its not a bug :'(

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZWR9.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect usage of `icon` property. You can't return a function that renders nothing, but you can return a function or nothing. In your case it should be:

```
icon={loading && spinnerIcon}
```